# How to debug selenium webdriver with phantoms and basic http auth?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to use selenium webdriver (python) with phantomJS to automate some boring administrative stuff that is done on a particular website. The website has a basic http auth mechanism. I run the following code but I am not getting anything (i.e nothing in screen.png or title). When I connect using wget using the same format ([https://username:password@mywebsite.com](https://username%3apassword@mywebsite.com)) it works and I get the initial homepage that should be shown on successful login. How do I debug this.. Is there a way to turn on verbosity so I can see what is is really getting. Also please note that using firefox or any other UI webdriver is not an option as I want to only run it from a linux box inside the firewall.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import getpass

login = "myname"
password = getpass.getpass("Enter password")
password = password.replace("@","%40")
url = "https://%s:%s@mywebsite.com/"%(login,password)

print url

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('./phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')

# go to the website 
driver.get(url)
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')

# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:o

print driver.title
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it navigate to the url?  If not have you tried using the `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url)`.  It also looks like you are saving your screenshot before getting it...

Comment: Thanks I will try that. BTW is there a way to produce more verbose output in this script?

Comment: Various things you could do.  The print for python is good for debugging or you can add a log utility in there to append to a log file.  Really depends on what you want to find.

Comment: thats not what i am asking for. if you read the original question you will see that it fails somewhere inside the selenium webdriver call. Want to see whats happening inside that.

Comment: Well I have never had to step through the webdriver code, but if you need to it's open source.  I would recommend you download the code and include it directly in your project so you can step through and debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the variant:

- change `password.replace()` to `urllib.quote()` since there could be more than `@` special symbols in password.
- change PhantomJS driver to Firefox (or any other) and you'll see what will exactly happen on your PC.
- after `driver.get()` use previously imported EC for waiting for some element on the page and only after that - take screenshot.